# Scroll accordion into view and open on page load

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I have a FAQ page with accordion. The behavior I want is when user clicks on a link to `localhost:3000/faq#why-choose-us` for example, the page should scroll to the accordion element with **why-choose-us** id and open the accordion. Currently, if I'm already on FAQ and click on a question, it would set the URL to `localhost:3000/faq#title-of-question` and open the accordion, but not when clicking on a link to here. Here is the code:

```js
{data.elements
            .map((feature, index) => (
              <Accordion
                id={`${feature.slug}`}
                key={index}
              >
                <a style={{ all: 'unset' }} href={`#${feature.slug}`}>
                  <AccordionSummary
                    expandIcon={<Iconify icon={ExpandMoreIcon} />}
                    aria-controls={`panel-content-${index}`}
                    id={`panel-header-${index}`}
                  >
                    <Typography sx={{ fontWeight: 600 }}>{feature.title}</Typography>
                  </AccordionSummary>
                </a>
                <AccordionDetails>
                  <Typography>{feature.description}</Typography>
                </AccordionDetails>
              </Accordion>
            ))}
}
```

[A page with the behavior I want](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html#can-i-use-inline-styles).

Answer (score 1):

When open the **why-choose-us** page use **scrollIntoView**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView
To show the accordion on the screen.

Then set **expanded** property for the accordion to **true**: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/accordion/

About clicking on a link you should use **useEffect** hook to determine the component initialization and inside the callback use the above approaches.

Comment: okay thank you that gave me a general idea, will try to implement this.